# Stability of MRAM values after power loss during write

Tags: mram

I'd like to put a file system on top of MRAM, and one of the more annoying design constraints is that I can lose power at any time, including during a write.

What behaviour can I expect to see in this case?

Intuitively, I would expect either

1. those bits that were currently being written with a different value than before to be unstable, and return 0 or 1 with a certain probability depending on where in the write cycle power was lost, *or*
2. writes to be always stable because the energy required to flip a bit is much smaller than what my bypass capacitors provide.

A quick search on "mram write stability after power loss" did not yield much, so

1. can I expect byte or bit granularity on an interrupted write, or is that implementation dependent?
2. can I expect whatever was written last to remain stable, assuming the clock stops before power drops below what the datasheet lists as minimum?

Comment: The energy for each write is much smaller than capacitor contents, sub pJ/bit. However, there will be always edge cases where you issue a write just before the UVLO flicks. A reliable controller must use a double buffer, whose contents it checks to be in sync with the main storage on power-on. The writing of this buffer should be an atomic operation

Comment: And bits in MRAM can't assume intermediate states. They are always single domain with only two states allowed by magnetic anisotropy. If the write didn't pack enough of a punch, the bit will remain in its original alignment.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a super cap.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I'm trying to establish whether I can avoid changing the board -- right now I get a "power good" signal, and the clock stops toggling if that goes low, but that may be in the middle of a byte. If I have the guarantee that what will be written will be bullshit, but *stable* bullshit, that is something my file system can work with.

Comment: If the power can be cut at any time, what does it matter how the underlying memory gets written? A file system has multiple parts anyway, the blocks of data itself, metadata about how many bytes it contains and how the data blocks are scattered around the memory. As you likely can't keep all these things consistent in one write, anything can happen. You likely need to have some sequencing that first writes all the updates and finally invalidates the old state to use the updated state. If a power good signal resets the MCU then it's already too late and write may be ignored, if it is SPI mem.

Comment: @Justme, exactly -- I'm trying to establish where my responsibility stops. For example, on flash memory I can have incompletely written cells that give unstable readings, and I can compensate for that by doubling up status flags.

Comment: It likely depends on the memory. Which exact chip you are using, and which is more important, not to need to repair the file system, not to lose any data, or which aspect? Would an SD card or eMMC chip be more suitable, they do wear leveling and remapping of flash blocks for you.

Comment: If your filesystem uses journalling, then it may not matter. Journalling file systems are designed so that all intermediate states are valid - even intermediate states with unstable bits.

Comment: @user253751, yes, I'm designing a file system. :)